# No such bean definition found?

Tags: java, spring, portlet

I am working on a portal project. When I deploy portlets into WebSphere I am getting `NoSuchBeanDefintionException` and I also checked for the package in `component-scan` and also googled about it, but I didn't find any solution. All the required packages in context.xml of every portlet.

Please see below for the logs

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.myhealthone.common.model.Account com.hca.cpp.coreservice.UserServiceImpl.account; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.myhea.common.model.Account] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@ringframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcesva:514)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor285)
        ... 147 more
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.myhealthone.common.model.Account] found for depy: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotatiowired(required=true)}
```

I added all the required packages to component-scan.

Comment: `com.myhea.common.model.Account` did you annotate this class with any stereotype like `Service` or `Resource` etc?

Comment: have you solved this issue? if yes, how did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

From [this link](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s12.html)

> Spring 2.5 introduces further stereotype annotations: @Component,
>   @Service and @Controller. @Component serves as a generic stereotype
>   for any Spring-managed component; whereas, @Repository, @Service, and
>   @Controller serve as specializations of @Component for more specific
>   use cases (e.g., in the persistence, service, and presentation layers,
>   respectively). What this means is that you can annotate your component
>   classes with @Component, but by annotating them with @Repository,
>   @Service, or @Controller instead, your classes are more properly
>   suited for processing by tools or associating with aspects. For
>   example, these stereotype annotations make ideal targets for
>   pointcuts. Of course, it is also possible that @Repository, @Service,
>   and @Controller may carry additional semantics in future releases of
>   the Spring Framework. Thus, if you are making a decision between using
>   @Component or @Service for your service layer, @Service is clearly the
>   better choice. Similarly, as stated above, @Repository is already
>   supported as a marker for automatic exception translation in your
>   persistence layer.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

     <context:component-scan base-package="org.example"/>

</beans>

@Service
public class SimpleMovieLister {

    private MovieFinder movieFinder;

    @Autowired
    public SimpleMovieLister(MovieFinder movieFinder) {
        this.movieFinder = movieFinder;
    }
}

@Repository
public class JpaMovieFinder implements MovieFinder {
    // implementation elided for clarity
}
```